# Using non-ascii characters with the default ascii encoding?

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, python-unicode

I use Python 2.7. This [page](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) says that:

> Python’s default encoding is the ‘ascii’ encoding

Indeed I have the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

But I open my interpreter and type this:

```
>>> 'É'
'\xc3\x89'
```

It looks like `utf8`:

```
>>> u'É'.encode( 'utf8' )
'\xc3\x89'
```

What happened? Did the default `ascii` raise `UnicodeEncodeError`? Did it trigger `utf8` encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminal is configured to use UTF-8. It sends UTF-8 data to Python. Python stored that data in a bytestring.

When you then print that bytestring, the terminal interprets those bytes as UTF-8 again.

An no point is Python actually interpreting these bytes as anything other than raw bytes, no decoding or encoding takes place on the Python level.

If you were trying to decode the bytes implicitly an exception would be thrown:

```
>>> unicode('\xc3\x89')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here Python used `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and the decoding failed.

For `stdin` input into the interactive prompt to create Unicode literals (using `u'...'`), Python does not use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` but the `sys.stdin.encoding` value:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

which Python takes either from the [`PYTHIONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) (if set), or from [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'UTF-8'
```

When reading Python source files, Python 2 would use ASCII to interpret such literals, Python 3 would use UTF-8. Both can be told about what codec to use instead using the PEP 263 source encoding comment, which has to be on the first or second line of your input file:

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

Comment: note: there is `os.device_encoding(fd)` in Python 3. It is worth mentioning it explicitely: changing source-code encoding has no effect on `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. REPL uses `locale.getpreferredencoding()` (that is why non-ascii inside literals may work by default without the encoding declaration) that may be different from `sys.stdin.encoding`